# how to make an input field that allows for searching in an outside search engine using Google API?

Tags: php, mysql, css, dictionary, location

I'm a beginner website designer and I was wondering whether there is a way to search for something in an outside search engine when you input a function in a field on your website. For example, the code I used to input a location for an event on my website is the following:

```
$query = '"$location"';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table`(`Location` ) VALUES (".$query.");");
```

However, how do I take that value I inserted into my database for location and subsequently search for it in another search engine if I want to look up that location on Google Maps. Thank you.

Edit: Many comments mentioned Google API, but being a beginner, I have no idea how to implement it. How do I specifically implement the Google geocode because that is really all I need.

Comment: you will need to use the search engine's API to search it. btw, your code is open for SQL injections attacks.

Comment: how do I protect my code from sql injections attacks?

Comment: never use user input directly in your SQL without [escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) it first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to query google maps for the location then you can use the geocode functions of the api

[Geocode example: ctrl+u to view the source](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html)

If you want to query a search engine, such as google which doesn't have an api for such types of search then you should look at the DOMDocument object

[Php DOMDocument reference](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

You'll be able to interact with this object in similar manner to how javascript interacts with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to find is the API's for the web services you want to query.

With the example you used of Google Maps you would reference the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) to query Google Maps and display a result.

Please note that because a service has an API it doesn't mean it is free so careful planning of your sites/apps is extremely important. You don't want to promise something like a maps integration just to find that you exceed the free query limits and have to pay thousands per month to display a map on your website/service. On the other hand if you have an existing revenue generating site/app then it could be worth paying the cash and doing it.

Good luck!